# Securely attaching a 4-ft 4"x4" lumber to concrete?

Tags: concrete, wood, fence, post

How can I attach/bolt a 4 ft treated 4x4 to concrete so it stands up securely?

Comment: Under what circumstances? "Securely" is a relative term. We'd do better with a description of the actual project at hand.

Comment: Agreed: we'll need more info (e.g. a diagram).

Answer (score 4):

If a picture is worth a thousand words
Here is a 4K word answer

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Next time maybe copy image addresses and use those rather than complete screenshots. And charge your phone.

Comment: The first example wouldn't hold anything upright. It's merely to secure the base location.